# Android OpenGL using float arrays instead of FloatBuffer for attribute

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

How can I feed an attribute value with an array? right now I am using  glVertexAttribPointer(maPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, mVertBuffer)
I want to use the array mVerts which contains 4 coordinates of 3 dimensional points.

Answer (score 0):

Opengl.org has the following to say:

> If a non-zero named buffer object is bound to the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER target (see glBindBuffer) while a generic vertex attribute array is specified, pointer is treated as a byte offset into the buffer object's data store. Also, the buffer object binding (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING) is saved as generic vertex attribute array client-side state (GL_VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING) for index index.

This means that you basically have to do this:

```
GLint currbuff =0;
//save the current bound buffer
glGetIntegerv(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING,&currbuff);
//unbind the currently bound buffer 
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0); //0 is reserved to unbind the currently bound buffer
//mVerts needs to be of type GLfloat *
glVertexAttribPointer(maPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, mVerts);
//rebind the previously bound buffer
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,currbuff);
```

you of course don't have to save/load if you don't use `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can do this in android? there is no type GLFloat* there, and glVertexAttribPointer only accepts Buffers, not arrays.
Is there any way to use say glVertexAttrib3fv or something like that?

Comment: @saaraz1: well, yeah `public static void glVertexAttrib3fv (int indx, float[] values, int offset)` should do the exact same thing if you call `glVertexAttrib3fv(maPosition,mVerts,0);`.

Comment: @saarraz1: did you check `glGetError()`?